# Cheap Techeilet?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, tzitzis, techeles

I follow minhag techeilet and I am on a university student's budget. Does anyone know where to get tzitziot with techeilet online for relatively little?

Comment: What kind of Techelet do you wear? _Murex trunculus_?

Comment: Its funny to see cheap techeiles together,when the gemara spoke of it it was rather expensive(not like its fake twin Kala ilan)

Comment: @sam You only go online to look for advice about discounts if the thing is generally pretty expensive.

Comment: Agreed but don't surprised if you get Kala ilan

Comment: It looks like the least expensive way to get murex techelet is directly from the dyers themselves, P'til Techelet, where the cheapest set of strings is $70.  Their resellers of course have them for more...

Comment: ..whereas the "Radzyner"(cuttlefish) strings are only $15 at worldofjudaica.com for the cheapest set.

Comment: I take my "resellers of course" comment back.  Ben's Tallit Shop  @ tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/tzitzit-strings-techelet/ has the P'til sets for only $60.

Comment: Mishkan HaTekhelet in Israel [sells](http://www.mishkan-hatchelet.co.il/170-%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9C-%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%AA) the RaMBa"M/RaAva"D shitot for ₪190 (~$52 at the current exchange rate).

Comment: @sam Yes, but how would you be able to tell? ;-)

Comment: _I follow minhag techeilet_ - what in the world is that supposed to mean? _minhag techeilet_?? (I know what you mean, but couldn't resist. This is just such a peculiar way of putting it.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann, some have the minhag to fulfil the mitzvah. Others are noheig to specifically not do so.

Comment: Hi! I tried tagging this question with the brand-new tag [ frugal ], but you [wrote](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/39490) that there were pre-existing tags which already covered that subject. Which tags? I don't think [ money ] quite covers it.

Comment: @tealhill, I don't think that we need a new tag for [frugal] since it's not something which is specifically about Judaism, more about life in general

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as there is no known company making Murex trunculus besides Petil Techelet, and on the other hand even the discounted techelet from then (for soldiers) is 100nis, I doubt anything lower will be the real deal. If on the other hand, you are interested in squib "techelet", which btw according to the radzin chassidim (I have spoken to the person who distributes it, son of the old Rebbe za"l) it is possible that both types can be halachically considered techelt. So if you want to go by that, they can go for as low as 50nis. BTW if you want me to send you Murex trunculus from Israel where if can be bought for cheaper, be in touch.

There is a "trick" called Ramabam Tafranim (literally Ramabam sewers [sewing], but meaning - rambam for poor people).
Assuming you did your reaserch you should know that there are three opinions about the amount of techelet strings you need. Rambam(1), Raavad(2) and Tosfot(4).
most people take Rambam because it is cheaper or because they think a Rabbi said so (for example there is an incorrect rumor [which we personally discounted] that Rabbi Aharon Lichtenstein said so. I personally hold Raavad.

In any case, to the **trick**:
Some people will buy Raavad or Tosfot and then cut the strings in half, and tie them to white strings making a string which is half white and half techelet, this will come out considerably cheaper (if you intended on having more than one pair). There are some opinions that this constitutes another knot and is halachicaly problematic while others don't but for more about this it would be wise to have a seperate topic about the knots in techelet as well as the opinions regrading the amount of strings (hint - some opinions claim that others make you over on deorita shatnez and say you are not wearing tzitzit at all)

Comment: What did R Lichtenstein tell you? (He has told different people different things in the past.)

Comment: Exactly, that he has not given a psak that rambam is halacha. Didn't ask him what was right as we weren't looking for a psak.

Comment: My Mesorah from RA"L is that he won't wear it at all "for personal reasons" but he feels that, if you choose to wear it, you should go with Rambam, which is what I do. I've never heard before that he tells different people different things. That aside, this answer provides very odd advice. OP: take that as a cautionary note.

Comment: Also, you said Rambam is the cheapest. It's not. IINM, it's the most labor-intensive and slowest to produce, and is therefore quite a bit more expensive than Raavad. (Tos. Might be more, because it uses twice as much dye as Raavad,, but I'm not sure if that brings up the price above Rambam. I wouldn't be surprised either way.

Comment: @SethJ I do not question your mesorah, but bear in mind that that doesn't cancel out my mesorah which is more first hadn than yours if it is only mesorah. So if you are the one who downgraded my answer I suggest you re-evaluate.
You may claim that my advice is odd, but you are welcome to pok chazei ma ama davar. I know first hand that people were doing this in Gush, Otniel, and Kiryat shemonah when I was in Yeshivah.
You are downright wrong about the Rambam pricing, I know because I have bought it many times. And you can see the pricing on the website i cite below.

Comment: pricing: http://judaica4you.com/categories/37833

Btw, we are not talking about the price to tie them, most people do not buy them tied.

Comment: @YaakovPinsky, fair enough about the pricing; I have not shopped for strings in a while, so I my information was from past experience and the explanation given at the time. As for the Mesorah, if RA"L told you one thing personally, it would add value to your answer if you'd include it. My Mesorah is not so far removed; it is from someone I trust who was given that guidance.

Comment: we just wanted to know if the rumor about him paskining that Rambam is the way to go was right and he said no.

Comment: YaakovPinsky If that's what you asked him then your "testimony" is really useless. Of course he wasn't going to say the he, the great Aharon Lichtenstein, succeeded in decided this machloket rishonim for all future generations. If you'd asked him, being a Gadol haDor and an Anav miKol Adam, for a personal recommendation, he would have in all likelihood told you to wear Rambam as he has told many people before you. @SethJ He has told some in the past that they can pick between Raavad and Rambam as both are reasonable opinions, but either way to tie Rambam-style chuliot.

Comment: @DoubleAA you are irrationally choosing to be very literal. I obviously (and said so in the last comment) that the questions was what does he paskin, not "who is right".

I think many people choose rambam because its cheap and are happy about this psak/rumor from Harel.
I have also heard from him that possibly according to the rambam, any other techelet strands would be considered invalid, and thus not counted in the 8, which would leave you with incomplete tzitzit transgressing the mitzvas of tzitzit and shaatnez. But apparently the only one who paskins this besides maybe Harel is R Rappaport

Comment: @YaakovPinsky I had read all of you comments just fine, and still reject that Rav Lichtenstein would _paskin_ anything on this issue. The fact is he has told many people _personally_ that he would recommend Rambam (or Raavad-Ramabm, per above) for them. So however you phrased your question to him, the response you got is largely immaterial given his track record.

Comment: I feel that you are not understanding me and this discussion is futile.

Furthermore I find it insulting that I take time to write an answer to a question that really doesn't fit the website's format, and give it a valid answer with various alternate solutions, only to have my answer down voted and the truthfulness of my statements questioned, only because people have a different opinion on the matter. I think you guys are really missing the point of open discussion. I'm out.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel insulted, but questioning other's positions is actually the point of open discussion. There is no need to be offended. Plus, Mi Yodeya is not a regular forum but a targeted Q&A site. If you feel a question is not appropriate you should flag it for closure to help maintain site quality. It's not usually worth writing an answer as closed questions can be removed at any time.

Comment: The source for the misquote might be that Rav Medan wears Rambam and tells everyone who asks to do so.

Comment: 1. Is _Ramabam Tafranim_ a typo for _Rambam Tafranim_?

Comment: 2. _over on deorita shatnez_ - how would that be? Where is the linen?

Answer (score 2):

The [Techeiles Chabura](http://www.techeiles-chabura.com) sells Bada"tz certified, murex-dyed strings for slightly less than Ptil Tekhelet's American costs.

Comment: Which Badatz is this?

Comment: @DoubleAA, the strings themselves are 'Edoh haChareidis, but I'm not certain about the murex

Answer (score 1):

I saw cheap radzyn techelet only for $15 on ben's tallit shop, but if you are wearing techelet from murex snail, you'll get the cheapest at techeiles-chabura.com, but the price not so far from ptil tekhelet, with the same quality and kashrut. You'll get The genuine ptil tekhelet with their genuine price only on chanut.tekhelet.com(or store.tekhelet.com) or at tzitzit.tallit-shop.com(ben's tallit shop). So far if i buy techelet, i have to buy from store.tekhelet.com, because they sell the nipputz lishma ones and the shipping price doesn't take much.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Yitharel! Thanks for the answer. Consider learning more about the site from this short [Beginners' Guide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775).

Answer (score 0):

When I was a soldier is Israeli army (about 7 years ago) I remember they (Ptil Tcheles) were selling it with 50% discount to soldiers. So, if you are soldier, you can use this option.

Another trick is as follows. If you make Tcheles by the opinion of Rambam you can buy a Tcheles of Raavad (same price) and split it to two sets of Rambam. I personally made it number of times. The idea is that in set of Raavad one whole string is colored, while in Rambam you need only half string to be colored. So, you buy one set of Raavad and another simple set of white strings. Then, you cut the colored and white *long* strings to halves. Tight the halves together, and you have two sets!

Comment: @Downvoter, what are your reasons?

Answer (score -1):

Going down the Bing list, and the Resellers list from P'til Techelet, it looks like "cheap techelet" is an oxymoron.  There's a non-Jewish vendor calling himself ["The Shoferman"](http://www.theshofarman.com/carttzitzit.htm)who claims to have $20.99 "Original Blue" strings using snail dyes, but he also says the color runs--a good indicator that they are NOT real techelet dyes, as the comments point out. That leaves P'til Techelet and their resellers.  P'til Techelet sells complete sets starting @ $70 on [their order page](https://tekhelet.com/order.htm). The comments also point out that their [Hebrew site](https://tekhelet.com/hebrew_site/heb_order.html) has the sets for NIS 160, (about $45.33), so if ordered there using NIS, they can get the real thing from the manufacturer @ at least 1/3 less than most other places - "relatively little", as requested.  All the resellers I've run across that have pictures of the package sell them for at least $70. with one exception - [Ben's Tallit Shop](http://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/tzitzit-strings-techelet/), who has them for $60.

Comment: But it's only 160 Shekels on their Hebrew order page.... https://tekhelet.com/hebrew_site/heb_order.html

Comment: I am skeptical. How is Shofarman able to sell it for much cheaper than anyone else? Why not name the supplier? What is this business about the dye rubbing off on your hands? I've never experienced that, and I thought the dye is [supposed to be steadfast](https://tekhelet.com/criteria.htm).

Comment: The jeans tzitzs what is that? They also sell hand made dye if you don't want the snail dye???

Comment: @Isaac Moses - good questions...I was thinking the same thing about the color fastness.. for the cost savings(if they're legitimate), maybe they buy a whole spool at a time from P'til and cut them to size themselves...?

Comment: Shofarman's sets look like Radzyner Techelet to me (I recognize the packaging).

Comment: @Isaac, Gary, et al, Shofarman is Christian. http://www.theshofarman.com/cartbkshofarvoc.htm

Comment: @SethJ, more explicitly, http://theshofarman.com/cartmessianictallitscriptures-1.htm and http://theshofarman.com/carttwins.htm

Comment: Oh s***t!  Sorry, folks... I was just trying to find the least expensive legitimate techelet for our questioner... I read his "G-d told me to start blowin the Shofar story" on his home page, I think.... Okay, skip him!  Looks like Ben's is the least expensive P'til techelet reseller, @ $60 + shipping...

Comment: ....not one thing on his homepage about his idolatry, thanks @Seth J for poking around and finding it...wow, pretty deceptive if someone's looking for a yirei shamayim vendor.